# Cassandra: For testing purposes, can I disable the TTL?

Tags: cassandra

We have testing we need to do using customer data which has TTL set on a table.  But for testing purposes, we need the data to not expire.

What's the best way to keep the data from expiring?

Simplest to understand would be a way to disable the TTL or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-expiring-columns). They suggest editing the value of the TTL Column in your data. You can just make it very large for your testing, and then change it back to a reasonable value afterwards.

Comment: We need a better solution.  Setting the TTL large is not working out.

Comment: we don't want to modify the TTL for millions of records.

also, sometimes, the TTL is expired already when we load the data.  this prevents support issues from being resolved

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how exactly you can disable the ttl, but can show you perhaps the most probable path. As you know Counter Column does not have TTL value associated, so if you can just check its implementation in thrift API and do the same (override) for normal Column, then may be you can achieve the functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand any of that.  I didn't know Counter Column does not have TTL nor do I know what Counter Column is :(